# How many watt-hours are theoretically necessary to produce 2kg of methane from sea water and air?

Tags: organic-chemistry, water

Given the composition of sea water in mol:
\begin{array}{lr}
  \ce{H2O}    &:& \pu{53.6 mol}\\
  \ce{Cl-}    &:& \pu{0.54 mol}\\
  \ce{Na+}    &:& \pu{0.469 mol}\\
  \ce{Mg^2+}  &:& \pu{0.053 mol}\\
  \ce{SO4^2-} &:& \pu{0.028 mol}\\
  \ce{Ca^2+}  &:& \pu{0.010 mol}\\
  \ce{K+}     &:& \pu{0.010 mol}\\
  \ce{Ct}~(\ce{CO2 + HCO3- + CO3^2-})
              &:& \pu{0.002 mol}\\
\end{array}

And the composition of air: 
\begin{array}{lr}
  \ce{N2}    &:& \pu{78.08 mol}\\
  \ce{O2}    &:& \pu{20.95 mol}\\
  \ce{Ar}    &:& \pu{0.934 mol}\\
  \ce{CO2}   &:& \pu{0.04 mol}\\
\end{array}

My general problem: considering that these concentration do not change during the reaction (excess of reactive) and that the product ($\ce{CH4}$) is taken away immediately, how much energy is theoretically needed to produce $\pu{2 kg}$ of $\ce{CH4}$ from the optimal mix of these two phases?

My specific questions:

- How can I be sure of which ions/molecule to definitely "get out" of the equation ?
- How can I be sure which reactions are the best ones for my case ?
- How do I do a dynamic equilibrium with more than 1 phase ?
- How do I do a dynamic equilibrium with added energy ?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: This is not homework ;-) It's personal development and curiosity.
And thanks for the Latex link, I'll try to learn it ASAP !

Comment: Please read the link that I have posted. This kind of question is considered homework here. It will probably be closed, before anyone hesitates to write up an answer.

Comment: Is it better now, or should I post the 3 question separately ?

Comment: Honestly I don't have any clue what you are trying to do. 2 kg methane equals to approximately 125 mol. The composition you have given is probably in mole fraction, not just mol (or the total amount of substance is missing). The carbon content is almost negligible, i.e. 0.002%, 0.04%. You would need a lot of it just to get some carbon. And how would you force (read: reduce) carbon dioxide to become methane? I really don't understand this.

Comment: Let's say we add some algae to the mix. Now we can ask how many watt-hours of solar energy are needed to produce 3 kg of hydrocarbons. Surely that question has been answered under the area of biofuels research.

Comment: For the sake of it, say I have unlimited amount of energy at hand (for example, I have a nuclear reactor onboard), and I am moving fast, so there is always enough reactive. What I am trying to estimate is how much energy I need to extract methane/carbon/any sort of fuel from the sea. 
Algae do that very well, but they cannot be boosted by electric power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly because I find the idea of a floating solar platform producing LNG using air and salt water amusing I went ahead and looked up some of the calculations needed for this answer.

First, I would like to thank you for doing your research ahead of time for the composition of air and salt water as well as solving for the bond energies using bond-dissociation.

For your separation of materials you need to go to thermodynamics for the minimum energy needed to get your reactants:

\begin{equation}
   E_\mathrm{sep} \geq \Delta G_\mathrm{mix} \equiv \Delta H - T \Delta S_\mathrm{mix}
\end{equation}

Using most separation techniques we can state that there are no reactions between components and so no enthalpy change, adding an additional simplifications of simple mixing with no interaction between compounds and ideal solutions leaves us with:

\begin{equation}
   E_\mathrm{min} = 
     \Delta G_\mathrm{mix} = 
     - T \Delta S_\mathrm{mix} = 
     -RT \sum_{i}(x_{i, \mathrm{initial}} \ln x_{i,\mathrm{initial}} 
       -x_{i, \mathrm{final}} \ln x_{i,\mathrm{final}})
\end{equation}
Using carbon dioxide for an example and assuming magic technology that works at $\pu{298 K}$ to $100\%$ separation (I agree with G M that any modern process will likely be much more energetically expensive than the minimum thermodynamics predicts):
 \begin{equation}
   E_\mathrm{min} =
     -RT[x_{\ce{CO2}} \ln x_{\ce{CO2}} + (1 - x_{\ce{CO2}}) 
       \ln (1 - x_{\ce{CO2}})] 
     = \pu{8.75 J/mol}_\mathrm{mixture} \text{ or } \pu{21.8 kJ/mol}_{\ce{CO2}}
\end{equation}

Using a similar treatment and your values for salt water, water takes $\pu{0.251 kJ/mol}$ water.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I wanted, I'll think on it tomorrow and accept it when I understand it fully.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

## Too much for making it of any practical interest

This question cannot be answered easily, there are too many factors. Bytheway it would not be practically convenient making such a process. With $\ce{CO2}$ as your only source of carbon, you would need an extremely energy dispendious [air separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_separation) apparatus to get some $\ce{CO2}$. You can get then hydrogen from water electrolysis and use  [Sabatier reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabatier_reaction) (you need a Nickel catalyst) to get finally methane.

Comment: Well, if it is of practical interest for the algae, why can't it be of practical interest for us ? (+1 by the way)

Comment: @Nygael you did not specify the usage of micro-organisms. If you looking for a biochemical path you should specify it otherwise people could think you need an industrial process

Comment: I did not specify any path. I want the theoretical minimum. Biochemical is not magic, it's chemistry just like electrolysis and Sabatier reaction, so the energy used by algae should, in theory, be the same if the process is efficient.

Comment: Sorry, by rereading I think the last comment sounds a bit aggressive. It was not meant to be.

Answer (score 1):

## A solution based on bonding energy and on the accepted answer

Considering the potential energy of each of the chemical bonds involved :

\begin{array}{lcr}
  \ce{CH4} &:& 4\times \pu{413 kJ/mol}\\
  \ce{CO2} &:& 2\times \pu{799 kJ/mol}\\
  \ce{H2O} &:& 2\times \pu{366 kJ/mol}\\
  \ce{O2}  &:&         \pu{495 kJ/mol}\\
\end{array}

And the equation:
$$\ce{CO2 + 2H2O = CH4 + 2O2}$$

We have for $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{CH4}$ a potential energy difference of:
$$(\pu{1598 kJ} + \pu{1868 kJ}) - (\pu{1652 kJ} + \pu{990 kJ})= \pu{824 kJ}$$

With the help of the accepted answer:
$\pu{21,8 kJ}$ is $\pu{6 Wh/mol}$ of $\ce{CO2}$ for dissociation.

Then, we need another $\pu{824 kJ}$, or $\pu{228 Wh/mol}$, for "retro-combustion".
To produce $\pu{1 t/year}$, we need $\pu{2.73 kg/day}$, which is $\pu{170 mol}$.
$$\pu{170 mol} \times (\pu{6 Wh/mol} + \pu{228 Wh/mol}) = \pu{39780 Wh}$$

With an average solar panel, we can produce $\pu{1000 Wh}$ per day per square meter. So in a theoretical world we would need $40$ square meter of solar panels to produce $\pu{1 t}$ of methane a year. Impractical, but not formally impossible.

Comment: That is completely neglecting that you need to concentrate the carbon dioxide first. That alone will consume much more energy than the final conversion to methane.

Comment: Isn't that what Rampalian answer is about ? But I know this is only theory, and that practically we are very far from achieving anything like this.